# Intuition Behind The Taylor Expansion Of The Derivative

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}^{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  and $f \in \mathcal{C}^{2}$. Suppose we have a $p \in \mathbb{R}^{N}$. Then by the MVT, we have:

$
\begin{equation}
f(x+p) = f(x) + p^{T}\nabla f(x+tp)
\end{equation}
$

For some $t \in (0,1)$. Now we can supposedly write:

$
\begin{equation}
\nabla f(x+p) = \nabla f(x) + \int_{0}^{1} \nabla^{2} f(x+tp) p \;dt
\end{equation}
$

---

I have three problems:

1. Intuitively, what is going on in the second expression?
2. What is the integral doing?
3. How can we visualize the action $\nabla^{2}f(x+tp)p$?

---

Comment: @caverac gave a great answer to the original question, but posted it after I edited it. I found my own geometric solutions to some of the original questions, but caverac's answer is really a great way to look at it. Can the mods fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will start with the $N=1$ case as a motivation. The MVP states that there exists a $t$ such that

$$
f(x + p) - f(x) = f'(x + tp) p \tag{1}
$$

Now, the fundamental theorem of calculus also states that

$$
\int_x^{x + p}{\rm d}y~ f'(y) = f(x + p) - f(x) \tag{2}
$$

From (1) and (2) you get

$$
f(x + p) - f(x) = \int_{x}^{x + p}{\rm d}y~ f'(y) \stackrel{t = (y - x)/p}{=} \int_0^1{\rm d}t~f'(x + tp)p \tag{3}
$$

In general this result can be extended to

$$
f(x + p) - f(x) = p^T\int_0^1 {\rm d}t~\nabla f(x + tp) \tag{3'}
$$

Your second equation can be found from (3'), just take the derivative again

$$
\nabla f(x + p) - \nabla f(x) = p^T\int_0^1{\rm d}t~ H(x + tp) \tag{4}
$$

where $H$ is the Hessian matrix of $f$. If you repeat the same argument over again you can find you third equation

Comment: I might be missing something, but why do we even need MVT?

Comment: @jjjjjj Eq. 1 is the MVT

Comment: Thanks yeah I see that, but I'm having trouble understanding how the MVT helps. In Eq. 3, the first equality is from FTC, the second from change of variables, but wouldn't this hold for any arbitrary change of variables?

Comment: @jjjjjj Oh I see, in the original post the question was how to move from Eq. 1 to Eq 3, please refer to the oldest version to see it

Comment: Oh... So I took a look through, and in $f(x+p) = f(x) + p^{T} \nabla f(x) + \frac{1}{2} p^{T} \nabla^{2} f(x+tp) p$, all we're doing is a first order Taylor expansion and using MVT for the remainder involving the Hessian. But for $\nabla f(x+p) = \nabla f(x) + \int_{0}^{1} \nabla^{2} f(x+tp) p \;dt$, if we're assuming we have the FTC, why/where do we use MVT? Sorry if I'm missing something obvious...

Comment: @jjjjjj Not for the first part, it comes into play in the derivation of the expansion of $f(x + p)$ up to second order

Comment: Ok, I think I'm on the same page. Thanks