# How is the Taylor formula applied here?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion

Let $d\in\mathbb N$, $\Lambda\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be connected and open and $A:\Lambda\times\Lambda\to\mathbb R$ be twice continuously differentiable. Let $x,x'\in\Lambda$ and $h,h'>0$. How can we show that $$\frac1{hh'}\left(A(x+he_i,x'+h'e_i)-A(x+he_i,x')-A(x,x'+h'e_i)+A(x,x')\right)\\=\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{\partial^2A}{\partial x_i\partial x'_i}(x+\theta he_i,x'+\theta'h'e_i)\:{\rm d}\theta\:{\rm d}\theta',$$ where $e_i$ denotes the $i$th standard basis vector? Clearly, this is an application of Taylor's formula, but I don't see how it is appield.

Comment: Have a look at this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2298029/intuition-behind-the-taylor-expansion-of-the-derivative/2298169#2298169

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would actually *not* show this using Taylor expansion.  It follows from (and generalizes) the mean value theorem.

First, let's define a new function $f : [0,h] \times [0,h'] \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$f(t,s) = A(x+te_i,x'+se_i)$$
Then, our problem is to prove
$$\frac{1}{hh'}\left(f(h,h') - f(h,0) - f(0,h) + f(0,0)\right) = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t \partial s} f(h\tau,h'\sigma)\;d\tau d\sigma$$
By changing variables in the integral, this becomes
$$f(h,h') - f(h,0) - f(0,h') + f(0,0) = \int_0^{h'} \int_0^h \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t \partial s} f(\tau,\sigma)\;d\tau d\sigma$$
Now, define a new function
$$g(t) = f(t,h') - f(t,0)$$
Then, by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus,
$$g(t) = \int_0^{h'} \frac{\partial}{\partial_s}f(t,\sigma)\;d\sigma$$
and
$$f(h,h') - f(h,0) - f(0,h') + f(0,0) = g(h) - g(0) = \int_0^h \frac{\partial}{\partial t} g(\tau)\;d\tau$$

---

From the previous work, it would suffice to show that 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int_0^{h'} \frac{\partial}{\partial s} f(t,\sigma)\;d\sigma =  \int_0^{h'} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t\partial s} f(t,\sigma)\;d\sigma.$$

This follows from the fact that (since $f$ is $C^2$), the difference quotients
$$\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial s}(t+k,\sigma) - \frac{\partial f}{\partial s}(t,\sigma)}{k}$$
converge to $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t \partial s} f(t,\sigma)$ uniformly in $\sigma$ for all $\sigma \in [0,h']$.  This is a particular case of the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).

Comment: Did you intend to define $f(t,s):=A(x+te_i,x'+se_i)$? Otherwise, your equation after "our problem is to prove" is not what we need to prove.

Comment: And why do the difference quotients converge uniformly with respect to $\sigma\in[0,h']$?

Comment: @0xbadf00d You're right that my definition of $f$ was not correct; I've edited.  I also had the wrong function in the difference quotient.  To see why the difference quotients converge uniformly, apply the mean value theorem and remember that continuous functions are bounded on compact sets.

Comment: Don't get it. For me this looks like a case for the dominated convergence theorem. In order to apply it, we need to bounded the difference quotients. By the mean value theorem, $$\left|\frac1\theta\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(s+\theta,t)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(s,t)\right)\right|\le\frac1{|\theta|}\sup_{\tilde s\:\in\:[0,\:h]}\left|\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial s\partial t}(\tilde s,t)\right|\tag1$$ for all $t\in[0,h']$. The supremum is clearly finite, since (as you've said) $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial s\partial t}$ is continuous in the first variable and $[0,h]$ is compact.

Comment: However, in order to apply the dominated convergence theorem, we need to bound further with respect to $t$, but why should the supremum over $t\in[0,h']$ of the right-hand side of $(1)$ be finite? I think this a problem in our assumptions. I'm assuming that $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial s\partial t}$ is continuous in each variable, and I guess that you assume that it is jointly continuous, right?

Comment: Yes, I assumed that $f$ was twice (jointly) continuously differentiable.  Is this not the case?  And if not, what do you mean when you say $f$ is twice continuously differentiable?

Comment: I've found the desired claim in a book and therein they say that a function $g:\Lambda\times\Lambda\to\mathbb R$ is called $C^m$ if the partial derivatives $\partial^\alpha_x\partial^\beta_yg(x,y)$ exist for all $x,y\in\Lambda$ and $|\alpha,|\beta|\le m$. Unfortunately, they don't state which kind of continuity assumption they impose on the $\partial^\alpha_x\partial^\beta_yg$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Could you provide a reference to the book?  It seems that your book may use different conventions than I'm used to.  Also, do you mean to say that $\partial_x^\alpha\partial_y^\beta g$ exists for $|\alpha|, |\beta| \le 2$, or just for $|\alpha| + |\beta| \le 2$?

Comment: I mean that it exists for $|\alpha|,|\beta|\le2$. You can find it on [page 72 of *stochastic flows and stochastic differential equations*](https://books.google.de/books?id=_S1RiCosqbMC&pg=PA72&lpg=PA72&dq=%22still+other+classes+of+function+spaces%22&source=bl&ots=ikbyycfGyX&sig=s36JTNhoVGp7AEq1mrD-NAPHjL4&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjlks_61avbAhXJZlAKHaQDB6EQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22still%20other%20classes%20of%20function%20spaces%22&f=false).

Comment: @0xbadf00d Thank you for the reference.  It looks like the author must be defining the space $\tilde{C}^{m}$ such that $\sup_{s,t} |\partial_{st}f| < \infty$, since otherwise equation $(3)$ would not define a seminorm.

Comment: I think so. Actually, the definition is a bit awkward in my opinion.